# How to sync Elementor Wordpress with Git?

Tags: wordpress, git, github, elementor

I built a website with wordpress. But for now, I made a change in local.

What is the best way to sync between local change with elementor to production with git?

Thanks!

Comment: You cant. Elementor is a page builder that saves values to the database. GIT observes file changes, all you need to do is export pages using Wordpress Exporter and import it into your live. You would need to delete exiting pages however or else it'll make duplicates. Make a backup first too.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for your reply!